# Can't install rustc version 1.7.0 with apt

Tags: ubuntu, rust, rust-cargo, apt

I am trying to install [Pachev_FTP server](https://github.com/pachev/pachev_ftp) on Ubuntu 20.1 I need to have have `rustc` installed on the system to use this. As mentioned in the Installation guide, I need to have rustc version `1.7.0`. But when I installed rustc with `apt install rustc` it installed version `1.53.0`. So I followed [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428772/how-to-install-specific-version-of-some-package) and tried installing the correct version with

```
apt install rustc=1.7.0
```

But it gives me an error saying `E: Version '1.7.0' for 'rustc' was not found`.  How do I install the correct version of rustc?

Comment: What happens if you just use `rustc` version 1.53.0 to compile this project?  Please note that this project hasn't been updated for four years: `rustc` version 1.7.0 might have been the current version at the time the project was active.  Note also that the project has a reported vulnerability (https://github.com/pachev/pachev_ftp/issues/4) so I would strongly recommend avoiding it: use an alternative FTP server instead.

Comment: when I install version 1.53.0 run the `cargo build --release` it errors at compiling `slog` (v1.5.2) saying `error: could not compile slog`. Also I am aware of the vulnerability. I am trying to reproduce this. Also I ran ``cargo test` , it errors saying the same thing.

Comment: Does this help? https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-can-i-revert-to-older-version-of-rust/20497

Comment: I followed the steps and I was able to install version 1.7.0. But I still have an error with running the command `cargo build --release`. This time it states that `failed to parse registry's information for: slog` and `Caused by: the given version requirement is invalid`. Not sure if the problem was with the version of rust of the dependency `slog`  (v1.5.2) itself.

Comment: I've never used Rust myself.  I would guess that the online package repository has changed its API since Rust 1.7.0 so the old version of Rust can no longer packages from it.

Comment: Is there a work around this to get this project to working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240418/discussion-between-kavishka-gihan-and-luke-woodward).

Answer (score 8):

Like [Luke Woodward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48503/luke-woodward) mentioned I was able to install rust version 1.7.0 by following [this](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-can-i-revert-to-older-version-of-rust/20497)

1. Uninstall the initial `rustc` installation (if installed)

```
apt autoremove rustc
```

2. Install `rustup`

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```

3. Add `~/.cargo/bin` to the $PATH (add this to your `.bashrc` (or your source file) to make this permanent)

```
export PATH=~/.cargo/bin:$PATH
```

4. Install the needed version of `rust`

```
rustup default 1.7.0
```

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that this project will compile with the latest version of Rust (1.57.0 at the time of writing), provided you update one of the dependencies:

- Edit `Cargo.toml` and change the line `slog="1.5.2"` to `slog="1.7.1"`.
- Update the `Cargo.lock` file by running `cargo generate-lockfile`.
- Re-run `cargo build --release`.

I got 21 warnings but it did at least compile.

This package won't compile on Windows as it requires a package that isn't available for Windows.

---

Note that as mentioned in the comments, this project has an unpatched security vulnerability.  It seems you are well aware of this and are trying to build this project only to practise reproducing this vulnerability, rather than actually using it to serve files.